# Need to fill Dropdown field by selecting a value from another dropdown

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, dropdown

I'm looking for a logic, where there is a dropdown which has some set of pre-loaded addresses(Street, city, country, state, ZIPCode). The country and state must be dropdown fields.

Now, on selecting one pre-loaded address, it should autofill the country and state.

For example, if the address: Street1, CityNAme, CountryName, StateName, ZIPCOde is selected from the drop down, it should search the CountryName, StateName from Country and State dropdowns and autofill accordingly.

Is it possible to write the code in javascript? I need to include this logic in my SharePoint2013 application.
Please let me know if the requirement is unclear.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Its simple javascript code need to implement that. and its basic

Answer (score 0):

Yes,we could achieve this with JS.

I don’t know the structure of your data, the data source and you didn’t specify the fields that need to be filled in automatically, so I can only give you some ideas.

Firstly,you need to make sure which column values can determine a unique object.

Secondly,Write these columns on the page, you can choose to hard code the values in them, or you can choose to get them from the data source.

Thirdly,When the object can be uniquely determined, you can filter out the object from the data source and automatically populate the value on the page through js/jQuery.

Comment: So, in my application I've a drop down field(which has 5 addresses and an Other option), and five text boxes. The functionality is when an address is selected, the data gets filled in respective text boxes(Street, city, state, country, ZIP Code) and when Other is selected it allows to fill manually. Now, my requirement is to change the text box into drop down only for country and state.
That means, when an address is selected from the dropdown it should auto fill the country and state dropdowns as well. Can we achieve it through javascript? Please explain